# best way to repeatedly map values from a sequence into an arg list?

Tags: clojure

Sorry for the noob question, but is there an good way to destructure values from a sequence like this..

```
(somefunc [[a b c] [1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9]] (prn a b c))
```

..with the a b c being assigned values until the sequence exhausted and letting me call a function on the args? doseq requires a *partition* of the right size..

```
(doseq [[a b c] (partition 3 [1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9])] (prn a b c))
```

Output:

1 2 3
4 5 6
7 8 9

That does what I want, but it seems like there should be a way to do this in s straightforward way *without* having to specify the partition. I found a solution with loop/recur but it's a lot more code and clearly non-idiomatic.  What's a good way to do this? Thanks!

Comment: Thanks! I see now that this specific problem doesn't count as "destructuring" since there's no structure to the input vector. It's the partition call that created the structure for me to match. I was hoping there was some core or contrib function that would do exactly what  my "somefunc" wants to do, but it doesn't seem to exist. The recursive solution seems pretty clean. Thanks again.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
(defn apply-to-three [f [a b c & xs]]
  (f a b c)
  (when xs
    (recur f xs)))

user=> (apply-to-three prn [1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9])
1 2 3
4 5 6
7 8 9
nil
```

Comment: that's the same partition and map does.

Comment: @edbond Naturally there are different ways to solve any given problem. A down vote usually implies that there is something fundamentally wrong with the answer, could you please elaborate what your problem is with mine?

Comment: I don't like reimplementing core functions, it's not idiomatic.

Answer (score 2):

```
(defn some-func
  [[a b c & rest :as all]]
  (prn a b c)
  (prn rest)
  (prn all)

user> (some-func [1 2 3 4 5 6 7])
1 2 3
(4 5 6 7)
[1 2 3 4 5 6 7]
```

Read more about destructing: http://java.ociweb.com/mark/clojure/article.html#Destructuring

Answer (score 2):

An alternate, lower-level solution using loop destructuring:

```
user=> (def coll [1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 10])
#'user/coll
user=> (loop [[a b c & more] coll]
user=*   (when a
user=*     (prn a b c)
user=*     (recur more)))
1 2 3
4 5 6
7 8 9
10 nil nil
nil
```

or use `when c` to exit after the last complete triplet.

Answer (score 0):

Using map and partition:

```
(map prn (partition 3 [1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9]))
```

Answer (score 0):

partition + map is all you need. Read about dorun, doseq and doall: http://onclojure.com/2009/03/04/dorun-doseq-doall/

```
user> (dorun (map #(apply prn %) (partition 3 [1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9])))
1 2 3
4 5 6
7 8 9
nil
```

Comment: You probably want to use `partition-all` instead of `partition`, otherwise you will lose values if the length of the collection is not dividable by 3.